# Pass by result-value and values of variables after method calls

Tags: parameter-passing

First, I understand the code is set up for pass by value, I think the question is hypothetical.

Also, this is not homework, it is from a study guide for the final.

This may appear to be a duplicate but the other threads had a lot of emphasis on the code not being set up for anything other than pass by value, so the comments were not very relevant.

I would like to know if b) and c) generate the same answer. 
I worked out the problem and have b) and c) with the same result but feel it may be a bit of a trick question, and easy to miss something. Here's the question and the code:

Consider the following program written in C syntax:

```
void  swap( int  a, int  b) 
{ 
    int  temp;   
    temp = a;   
    a = b;   
    b = temp; 
}
void  main() 
{ 
    int  value = 2, list[5] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};   
    swap(value, list[0]);   
    swap(list[0], list[1]);   
    swap(value, list[value]); 
}
```

For each of the following parameter-passing methods, what are all of the values of the variables value and list after each of the three calls to swap?

a) Passed by value

b) Passed by reference

c) Passed by value-result

Comment: Please narrow down your problem. Currently, it feels like a homework assignment I am afraid!

Comment: Even if it were a homework assignment I am not asking for an answer. I'm asking for confirmation b) and c) yield the same result. Also, what schools still have homework assignments this late in the year? It is from a final study guide, we are not turning it in for any credit.